# dll not detected in Detected Dependencies in Visual Studio 2008 C++ Installer

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, installation

I have a C++ project that depends on a four external dlls. I can compile my project fine in Visual Studio, so I know my C++ compiler and linker reference paths and libraries are correct. I had to copy the dlls to the Release and Debug directory to allow the dlls to be loaded when I run the executable.

When I come to build the installer, the external dlls are not listed as detected dependencies in the installer explorer. If I copy the dlls to the Release or Debug directory for the project, two of the dlls are detected but two aren't.

What am I doing wrong?

I tried running Dependency Walker on the Debug version and it detected all four dlls correctly. Is there some way to export the result of Dependency Walker into the Detected Dependencies in VS?

Comment: What kind of installer and VS version are you using?

Comment: Just don't rely on the installer? Suppose you load libraries dynamically using the LoadLibrary function, the installer will never be able to figure that out anyway

Comment: @Amadeusz: I'm using VS2008 9.0.21022.8. What do you mean by 'what kind of installer' ?

Comment: @user12066: Don't I need to distribute the dll in the installer anyway? Even if I tried to use LoadLibrary, if the dll isn't available on the target PC the executable won't run.

Comment: I'm asking if you are using Visual Studio Installer, or some other software that can create windows installer packages? OR mabye you are writting script for Windows Installer by yourself?

Comment: @Amadeusz: Sorry, yes I am using a Visual Studio intaller.

Comment: *Don't I need to distribute the dll in the installer anyway?* yes, that is my whole point: installer can never detect all dependencies reliably, so you must manually include all dependencies, so why bother asking questions about how to have the installer detect dependencies: answer is it can't :]

Comment: Then when comes to the dependency detection don't relay on Visual Studio Installer and add your extra dlls as regular files to the Application Folder Directory. I don't think that you are doing something wrong VSI just don't seem to detect dependencies correctly. I had the same problem myself when I used VSI. Don't forget adding VS Redistributables also :)

Comment: Thanks guys - it's a bit annoying to have to copy some dlls along with the installer, but if the dependency detection isn't reliable I guess it's the only way.